# Explorer: is it installed by default?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to run the vim's Explorer running `:Ex` but it says: `Not an editor command: Ex`.

I thought Explorer was installed by default in vim. is that true? how to install it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my [understanding](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/the-file-explorer/), `:Explore` command is added by [netrw pluging](https://github.com/vim-scripts/netrw.vim). It's usually distributed with Vim. In your case you will have to manually install it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you just need to have (at least) the following two lines in your .vimrc:

set nocp
filetype plugin on